# Node.js : need help to create command line interface

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm developing command line interface with node.js. Can we have custom console like mysql? Like, if we type mysql and enter in console it will come as `mysql>` so we can do all mysql related operation until we exit. Like that in node.js

```
> node hello
hello> help
hello> list apps
.
.
hello> exit
>
>node world
world>operation related to world
.
.
world>exit
> 
// or if it is executable
>hello
hello>help
hello>list app
hello>exit
>
```

It would be great if you give some suggestion.

Comment: Seems like you want to create a [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html). Check this out, though I haven't tried something lime it myself: [How to create and use a custom REPL](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/REPL/how-to-create-a-custom-repl)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look it out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Check out [Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal). It was made for this exact purpose.

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

... // your app code

vorpal.command('list apps')
  .action(function (args, cb){
    var self = this;
    myapps.forEach(function(app) {
      self.log(app.name);
    });
    cb();
  });

vorpal
  .delimiter('hello>')
  .show();
```

And then you'll have this:

```
$ node hello.js
hello> list apps
..
..
hello>
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote Vorpal.*